# Finding certain characters in a line of string

Tags: c++

I want to be able to a string that contains certain characters in a file that contains one string per line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  string line;
  ifstream infile;
  infile.open("words.txt");

  while(getline(infile, line,' ')){
    if(line.find('z')){
      cout << line;
    }
  }
}
```

That's my attempt at finding all the string that contains the character `z`.

The text file contains random strings such as

```
fhwaofhz
cbnooeht
rhowhrj
perwqreh
dsladsap
zpuaszu
```

so with my implementation, it should only print out the strings with the character `z` in it. However, it seems to be reprinting out all the contents from the text file again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

In your file the strings aren't separated by a space (`' '`) which is the end delimiter, they are separated by a end of line (`'\n'`), that is a different character. As a consequence, in the first `getline` everything goes to `line`. `line` contains all the text in the file, including z's, so all the content is printed. Finally, the code exits the `while` block after running once because `getline` reaches the end of the file and fails.

If you run this code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream infile;
  infile.open("words.txt");

  while(getline(infile, line,' ')){
    std::cout << "Hi";
    if(line.find('z')){
      std::cout << line;
    }
  }
}
```

"Hi" will be only printed once. That is because the `while` block is only executed once.

Additionaly, see that `line.find('z')` won't return 0 if not match is found, it will return `npos`. See it running this code (As it says [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream infile;
  infile.open("words.txt");

  while(getline(infile,line)){
    std::cout << line.find('z');
    if(line.find('z')){
      std::cout << line << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution:**

Use `getline(infile,line)` that is more suitable for this case and replace `if(line.find('z'))` with `if(line.find('z') != line.npos)`.

```cpp
while(getline(infile,line)){
    if(line.find('z') != line.npos){
      std::cout << line << "\n";
    }
  }
```

If you need to put more than one string per line you can use the operator `>>` of `ifstream`.

**Additional information:**

1. Note that the code you posted won't compile because `string`, `cout` and `ifstream` are in the namespace `std`. Probably it was a part of a longer file where you were using `using namespace std;`. If that is the case, consider that it is a bad practice (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

**Full code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream infile;
  infile.open("words.txt");

  while(getline(infile,line)){
    if(line.find('z') != line.npos){
      std::cout << line << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you did for the full code, it's still printing out the entire list

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the problem of `line.find()`. I have just corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

`getline` extracts characters from the source and stores them into the variable `line` until the delimitation character is found. Your delimiter character is a space (`" "`), which isn't present in the file, so `line` will contain the whole file.

Try `getline(infile, line, '\n')` or simply `getline(infile, line)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The method `find` returns the index of the found character, where 0 is a perfectly valid index. If the character is not found, it returns `npos`. This is a special value whcih indicates "not found", and it's nonzero to allow 0 to refer to a valid index. So the correct check is:

```
if (line.find('z') != string::npos)
{
    // found
}
```

Comment: this worked, but i don't know how your syntax works